# Read space delimited file with variable number of columns in C

Tags: c, file, variables, structure

So I have files formatted as follows:

```
2
4 8 4 10 6
9 6 74
```

The first line is actually the number of rows that the file will have after it. I want to read the files line by line (note there are different number of tokens in each line but all have the format: 1 token and then an unspecified number of pairs of tokens) and do two things for each line:

1) Know how many tokens are in this line.

2) Assign each token to a variable. Using structures similar to:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned start; //start node of a graph 
  unsigned end;   // end node of a graph
  double weight;  //weight of the edge going from start to end
} edge ;

typedef struct {
  unsigned id;   // id of the node
  unsigned ne;   // number of edges adjacent to node
  edge *edges;   // array of edge to store adjacent edges of this node
} node;
```

Some code:

```
FILE *fin;
unsigned nn;
node *nodes;

fin = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
fscanf(fin,"%u\n", &nn);

nodes = malloc(nn*sizeof(node));

for(i=0; i < nn; i++) { //loop through all the rows
/*grab the row and split in parts, let's say they are part[0], part[1]... */
/*and there are N tokens in the row*/
  nodes[i].id=part[0];
  nodes[i].ne=(N-1)/2; //number of pairs excluding first element
  nodes[i].edges=malloc( (N-1)/2)*sizeof(edge) );
  for(j=0; j< (N-1)/2; j++){
    nodes[i].edges[j].start=part[0];
    nodes[i].edges[j].end=part[2*j+1];
    nodes[i].edges[j].weight=part[2*j+2];
  }
}
```

I need to figure out how to do the part comented inside the first for loop to get the number of tokens and each one of them as a simgle token to asign. Any ideas?

EDIT: to make things clear, each line will have first one integer, and then a variable number of pairs. I want to store data as follows:

if the file reads

```
2
4 8 4 10 6 //(2 pairs)
9 6 74 //(1 pair)
```

then

```
nn=2;

node[0].id=4;
node[0].ne=2; //(2 pairs)
node[0].(*edges) //should be a vector of dimension ne=2 containing elements of type edge

node[0].edges[0].start=4; //same as node[0].id
node[0].edges[0].end=8;
node[0].edges[0].weight=4;

node[0].edges[1].start=4; //same as node[0].id
node[0].edges[1].end=10;
node[0].edges[1].weight=6;

node[1].id=9;
node[1].ne=1; //(1 pair)
node[1].(*edges) //should be a vector of dimension ne=1 containing elements of type edge

node[1].edges[0].start=9; //same as node[1].id
node[1].edges[0].end=6;
node[1].edges[0].weight=74;
```

Comment: [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)

Comment: So actually you don't know how to read a file in C **?** because that code missing.

Comment: You wanted to split lines, Gunb need to look for `\n` in file to read lines. And of-course after that parse using `strtok()`

Comment: Thanks for commenting the structs - is it true that a node is simply going to be an x,y couple, like the point (x,y)?

Comment: I've added a small summary of how I do want the variables for each line stored in the structures in a small example. I hope it helps clarify things.

Comment: does the vertex graph in the picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29) kind of look like something the file we are reading will represent?

Comment: Okay, your summary helps - I don't need you to answer that last question.

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there with me.  By now, you have probably figured out the whole thing yourself, but in case not, there is a re-write of my original attempt below that more closely follows the intent of your question (how to populate the struct with file entries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code produces the results you described,   It initializes your nested struct member `edge`, and uses strtok.  With `strtok()`, I included the \n as part of the delimiter in addition to a space `" \n"` to prevent the newline from giving us trouble (see other comments on that below)

***Note:*** you have to free memory where I have indicated, but before you do, preserve the intermediate results (in the structs) or it will be lost.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

typedef struct {
  unsigned start;
  unsigned end;
  double weight;
} edge ;

typedef struct {
  unsigned id;
  unsigned ne;
  edge *edges;
} node;

int GetNumPairs(char *buf);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *tok;
    char lineBuf[260];
    int i=0, j=0;
    int nn; //number of nodes
    char countPairsBuf[260];

    fp = fopen("C:\\dev\\play\\numbers.txt", "r");
    //get first line of file for nn:
    fgets (lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), fp);
    nn = atoi(lineBuf);
    //create array of node with [nn] elements
    node n[nn], *pN;
    pN = &n[0];

    //read rest of lines, (2 through end)
    i = -1;
    while(fgets (lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), fp))
    {
        i++;
        //get number of items in a line
        strcpy(countPairsBuf, lineBuf);
        pN[i].ne = GetNumPairs(countPairsBuf); //number of edges (pairs)
        if(pN[i].ne > 0)
        {   //allocate *edges struct element
            pN[i].edges = malloc((pN[i].ne)*sizeof(edge));
            //get first item in new line as "line token" and "start"
            tok = strtok(lineBuf, " \n");
            while(tok)
            {
                pN[i].id = atoi(tok);
                //now get rest of pairs
                for(j=0;j<pN[i].ne;j++)
                {
                    pN[i].edges[j].start = pN[i].id;
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                    pN[i].edges[j].end = atoi(tok);
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                    pN[i].edges[j].weight = atoi(tok);
                }
                tok = strtok(NULL, " \n"); //should be NULL if file formatted right
            }
        }
        else  //pN[i].ne = -1
        {
            //error, file line did not contain odd number of elements   
        }

    }
    //you have to free memory here
    //but I will leave that to you
    fclose(fp);

}


//GetNumPairs
int GetNumPairs(char *buf)
{
    int len = strlen(buf);
    int numWords=0, i, cnt=0;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if ( isalpha ( buf[i] ) ) cnt++;
        else if ( ( ispunct ( buf[i] ) ) || ( isspace ( buf[i] ) ) )
        {
            numWords++;
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }//if odd number of "words", return number of pairs, else error
    return (((numWords-1)%2) == 0) ? ((numWords-1)/2) : (-1);
}
```

Comment: Okay, ill edit this.  What are the struct members "start" and "end" use for?

Comment: `start` and `end` represent the start and end nodes of an edge in a graph. I am not very familiar with the `++i` syntax. It does use the old value of `i` and then increment its value?

Comment: @ryyker \n is not necessary in strtok; it even confused me :)

Comment: ++i, as opposed to i++, increments i _before_ it is used.  another question:  which struct member is used to store number of token pairs in each line?  i.e. do you need to see how to store an array of token pairs within the struct?

Comment: by the way, I am working on example, this one using structs you have provided.  Can you please edit your post and place comments (//..) at the end of each struct member, for both structs, telling what each member is for (like what you said for start and end above.  Thanks.

Comment: And the number of token pairs in each line will be stored in the respective `node.ne`. It will also correspond to the dimension of the array `node.edges` since each pair corresponds to one adjacent edge.

Comment: On general principles, you should use `strtok_r` rather than `strtok` to avoid reentrancy problems.  It's not a problem here, but in more complex cases (or if you use mulitple threads) it can be.

Comment: @RobinRobinovic - actually it is.   `atoi()` if passed this char value, will interpret `\n` and return a zero.  This would be an edge condition to be avoided given we are dealing with integers, lines in a file, and most probably `\n` at the end of each.  But, really, there are more important issues, i.e. that my example so far does not answer some of the more fundamental questions OP is asking, i.e. how to populate structs with relevant values.  Working on that now.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - yes, I am familiar with concept of re-entrant code, and when dealing with need for multi-threaded environments, I do pay attention to that.  Thanks, agreed, not necessary here.

Comment: @RobinRobinovic: the `\n` is a good idea; it prevents the newline being treated as part of the last token on the line.  Remember, `fgets()` includes the newline in the output.

Comment: This seems to be what I was expecting. I tried to do on my own but had problems mainly on the `GetNumPairs` function. I kind of understand your version but I am not familiar with some of the functions used. Could you verbose a little bit about what it is doing exactly in the loop? And I don't get what the `cnt` variable is for either.

Comment: I've been doing some test on the function `GetNumPairs`. Not that it is important from the point of view of my question but since my file will be space delimited only the `isspace ( buf[i] )` is really needed and the `cnt` variable is never actualized since there are no letters either. One last question: the end-of-line character (`\n`) gets stored in a single element of the array `buf`, right? That is, `buf[len-1]='\n'` and not `buf[len-2]='\'` and `buf[len-1]='n'`.

Comment: Regarding the loop in `GetNumPairs()` - cnt is an artifact  - from a version of this same function where I wanted to keep track of the length of each word(sorry :). The loop is simply "tokenizing" one line buffer from your file per call.  Each space I find lets me know to increment `numWords`, the word count.  I am looking for an odd number of words, per your file description.  I use the arguments in the ternary operator, `?:;` (shortcut for if, then, else) to test for an odd number of words, if odd, then pass back number of pairs `(numWords-1)/2`, else return an error indication using `-1`.

Comment: Regarding `\n`, or "newline": You are (partially) correct, so for a single line read with `fgets()`, I would receive something that looks like this: "4 7 4 9 34\n".  The `\n` character is actually only a single byte, equal to 0x0A, or decimal 10.  It is represented by two symbols "\" and "n", but together, they represent only on thing.  ***[Look Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)*** for a list of common escape symbols used in C.  So, `buf[len-1] == '\n';` is a true statement.  Also, `buf[len] == '\0';` is a true statement.

Comment: Important to note that the `\n` character is not required, but the `\0` character is.  (by definition, a C string is a null terminated array of `char`).  if we used `len=strlen(lineBuf);` for the string above, len would be 11, counting all numbers, spaces _and_ the newline.  But it would not count the `\0`.  Important to remember when allocating memory for a string.  Always allocate `len + 1`.